# Using Prototype with an introductory program

Tags: javascript, prototype

Q: Do I need to use prototype for anything more than one liners?

I love the [Mary live-codes a JavaScript game from scratch video](https://vimeo.com/105955605), but I have an issue with the complexity of her proof-of-concept. If you pause it at 3:14, you can see that her beginning code is wrapped in:

```
;(function() {
})();
```

In order to namespace everything. But in my mind, a proof-of-concept doesn't need this rather obscure looking setup. Inside the immediately invoked anonymous function is this:

```
var Game = function(canvasId) {
   var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
}
Game.prototype = {
}
window.onload = function() {
   new Game('screen');
}
```

Now, only 1 line is really necessary. I understand that it's all housekeeping and that if you're ever going to grow past a proof-of-concept, you need all this scaffolding, but all of that could have been written in a single line of code:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
```

And here I'm using 'myCanvas' instead of var canvas and "screen" because the learner is trying to decipher what part is a JavaScript keyword and what part is the user's own naming. And I believe screen is a JavaScript keyword.

Is prototype something that a typical JavaScript programmer would use, or is Mary so advanced that she uses it as a matter of course? In other words, is her methodology too advanced for a proof-of-concept? I know that's a bit of a stretch because a proof-of-concept might be a couple of lines of code whereas this is maybe 200.

Comment: Question: is the coding example supposed to be aimed at _absolute_ beginners at JavaScript or at people who are new to _graphics programming_?

Comment: You're asking opinions on the better way to teach beginners? That would be pretty far off topic. And `screen` is not a JS keyword. But yes, prototypal inheritance is typical JS code.

Comment: Good principles is something beginners especially need to learn.

Comment: Right, I watched the beginning couple of minutes of the video (I hadn't before my question) and I'm still not sure. The description doesn't say, nor does the start of the talk. My guess is that it's aimed at people who have _some_ knowledge of JS. The `;(function() {})();` is a pretty widely known one, I would have thought. Probably a bit "old-school" nowadays, but still should be recognisable for people with some web experience. So, I don't think it's _that_ confusing to the audience.